# How to convert a float pointer to an int pointer in C++?

Tags: c++

I understand that reinterpret_cast may do it, but I think it did not do the data conversion. I don't want to loop over and do them one by one, and wonder whether there is an elegant way to do both the pointer type and data type conversion.
Thanks!

Comment: We need more scope to this. That alone sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is definitely not the way to do it.

Comment: What is purpose for conversion?

Comment: Hi, could explain what you mean by "We need more scope to this"?

Comment: Create a SSCC(C)E -- http://sscce.org/ -- that describes what you want to do.  It should compile, even if there is a step you don't understand.  Describe what the more general problem is that you want to solve -- provide some context to the short self contained example as well.

Comment: @HailiangZhang, I mean there's probably a better way to solve your general problem than resorting to this, but we have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What "data conversion" are you talking about? There's no meaningful "data conversion" for unrelated pointer types and value conversion between `int` and `float` has absolutely nothing to do with any pointers. So, what is this question about exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, as I am assuming, you have some `float*` that points to the first element in an array of `float`s and you want to use them as `int`s then I suggest a few options:

1. If you don't want `float`, don't get `float`s. Just store an array of `int`s in the first place.
2. Likewise, if you don't want `int`s, then change your code to use `float`s throughout.
3. If you do indeed want to have an array of `float`s and at some point want to convert them to `int`s, do it when you need it. Use `static_cast<int>` to do the conversion on each element in a safe manner.
4. If you'd like to convert the whole array at once, then I suggest you do something like so:

   ```
   float float_array[N] = /* ... */;
   std::vector<int> ints(float_array, float_array + N);
   ```
5. Alternatively, if you really want to stick with arrays, use `std::copy`:

   ```
   float float_array[N] = /* ... */;
   int int_array[N];
   std::copy(float_array, float_array + N, int_array);
   ```

   The `std::vector` above is much preferred, however.

Comment: Great answers! Apparently I don't want to use 3. My scenario is convert a float array to an int array, and load this int array to GPU. I am not sure the GPU API will take STL object or not, so I may need to do 5.  However, if the STL vector can be easily converted or casted to a regular array, maybe I can do it. Thanks!